# PHP: how to add a random character in a string at random position

Tags: php, string

How can i add a single random character (0-9 or a-z or - or _) at a random place in a string.

I can get the random position by following:

```
$random_position = rand(0,5);
```

Now How can i get a random number ( 0 to 9 ) **OR** random character (a to z) **OR** (-) **OR** (_)

and finally how i can add character to the above string in the above random position.

For example following is string:

```
$string = "abc123";
$random_position = 2;
$random_char = "_";
```

the new string should be:

```
"a_bc123"
```

Comment: Really? And what is the difference between position 0 and 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = "abc123";
$random_position = rand(0,strlen($string)-1);
$chars = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM0123456789-_";
$random_char = $chars[rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)];
$newString = substr($string,0,$random_position).$random_char.substr($string,$random_position);
echo $newString;
```

Comment: This character map includes capital letters as well, which the OP didn't seem to indicate.

Comment: Well, it does, but the map can be safely edited as per requirement.

Comment: @Shef, yes i did not want to include capitals, but i removed them.

Comment: Please have a look at @rrapuya's use of `substr_replace()` - Pretty nice replacesment for the `substr()` usage.

Comment: @Phliplip, Thanks. i surely did.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
<?php 

   $orig_string = "abc123";
   $upper =strlen($orig_string);
   $random_position = rand(0,$upper);
   $int = rand(0,51);
   $a_z = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
   $rand_char = $a_z[$int];


   $newstring=substr_replace($orig_string, $rand_char, $random_position, 0);

   echo 'original-> ' .$orig_string.'<br>';
   echo 'random-> ' .$newstring;
?>
```

Comment: I like your solution, you're the only one that thought of using substr_replaces with a zero length. From the manual; **"Of course, if length is zero then this function will have the effect of inserting replacement into string at the given start offset."** But you are missing the digits, _ and - in the characterset, and I don't think sunjie wants the uppercase included. Also your `rand()` should utilize `strlen()` like the other answers.

Comment: well havent think about utilizing strlen() in rand() i just realized when i get to read their answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'abc123';
$chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';
$new_string = substr_replace(
    $string,
    $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)],
    rand(0, strlen($string)-1),
    0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// map of characters
$map = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_';
// draw a random character from the map
$random_char_posotion = rand(0, strlen($map)-1); // say 2?
$random_char = $map[$random_char_posotion]; // 2

$str = 'abc123';

// draw a random position
$random_position = rand(0, strlen($str)-1); // say 3?

// inject the randomly drawn character
$str = substr($str, 0, $random_position).$random_char.substr($str,$random_position);

// output the result
echo $str; // output abc2123
```

Comment: Would a `$random_char_position` of 2 not indicate that `$random_char` became '2' ? Just saying ;)

Answer (score 0):

get the string length:

```
$string_length = strlen($string);//getting the length of the string your working with
$random_position = 2;//generate random position
```

generate the "random" character:

```
$characters = "abcd..xyz012...89-_";//obviously instead of the ... fill in all the characters - i was just lazy.
```

getting a random character out of the character string:

```
$random_char = substr($characters, rand(0,strlen($characters)), 1);//if you know the length of $characters you can replace the strlen with the actual length
```

breaking the string into 2 parts:

```
$first_part = substr($string, 0, $random_position);
$second_part = substr($string, $random_position, $string_length);
```

adding the random character:

```
$first_part .=  $random_char;
```

combining the two back together:

```
$new_string = $first_part.$second_part;
```

this may not be the best way, but I think it should do it...