# Put random characters into a string

Tags: php, encryption, random

For example:

```
$myString = "Hello World";
```

I want to put random characters into it, so it becomes something like this:

```
$myString = "~!H@e#llo$*Wo-rld+";
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok, many ways to do it, but why?

Comment: @Gerry Just making a newbie encryption. Please help me out :)

Comment: Well see this for an example of how to do it once, then you just need to run it in a loop for the number of characters you want inserted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503176/php-how-to-add-a-random-character-in-a-string-at-random-position

Comment: Ok, here goes my guess... is this for a CAPTCHA?

Comment: @Gerry Nope, thanks for the link though :)

Comment: lol, then can you tell me what it's for? I'm curious. I don't see any straight forward way for a computer to decrypt your "encryption"  (hense thinking it was for humans via a CAPTCHA) and without decryption, what is the point?

Comment: I will have a decryption as well. Just making something like a anti-leech. So people can't easily leech from my site. Easy to bypass but It'll block some leechers, good enough for me.

Comment: That sounds awfully like a CAPTCHA, but ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

naive algorithm:

```
$len=strlen($myString); // we will not recalc it
$allowed=array('!','~');
for(int $i=0;$i<$countOfChars;++i){
    $x=rand(0,$len); //put after $x characters;
    $char=$allowed[array_rand($allowed)];
    $myString=substr($myString,0,$x).$char.substr($myString,$x);
    ++$len; 
}
```

But I think you should forget about this idea and you other way to solve your problem